# Typecasting two user-defined objects in C++ -- possible?

Tags: c++, casting, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to get a C++ code base that works on a desktop to run on an Android phone. The code does stuff with images and presently uses a user-defined class called CqByteImage to interface with images. The NDK interfaces with the camera using an IplImage object.

Now, for me to make minimal changes, I wonder if there is an easy to type cast the IplImage as the other?

If not, my only solution seems to be to re-write the functions to accept IplImage now - which can be tricky since I have over 30.h/cpp files.

Suggestions welcome. I can post clarifications if my questions are vague.

Help much appreciated,
M

Comment: Simply casting one as the other seems like it almost certainly won't work, and from memory Java is stricter about stuff like that than C++ which may prevent some of this kind of thing on the phone. Is there some relationship between CqByteImage and IplImage that makes you think that one can be used as a substitute for the other?

Comment: They are both custom object types that deal with images and have "similar" properties. That said, I am inclined to agree with you. I don't think there is any reason that they are implicitly compatible for typecasting.

Answer (score 2):

You won't want to do this by casting or re-writing the functions.

You'll want to create a method that creates a CqByteImage from an IplImage, either by pulling all the data from the IplImage or by implementing the methods in CqByteImage in terms of the methods in IplImage.

Comment: Fantastic! Then my follow up question would be, would the use of a non-native object type create any complications for NDK/Java ?

Presently, I have a function like
int AndroidRead(int idx, image_pool* pool){

cv::Mat greyimage = pool->getGrey(idx);
IplImage image = greyimage;

CqByteImage imSrcGray;

<Some function calls using the object imSrcGray>
}

But when I compile, I get a lot of undefined references for CqByteImage' constructor/destructor (CqByteImage is a template class and NDK is not very template friendly?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making a wrapper to use your IplImages as CqByteImages? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

If the images have a compatible internal representation, this might even be very efficient.

Comment: Wow! Another nice idea. I am only concerned, as I stated previously of the use of non-native object types with NDK. 

Suggestions?